# passing values from a strange list in python

Tags: python, list, variables

I want to pass the first value (number) of the inside list to a dict if the words match

buffer :

```
 ['from', 
'landi', 
'stsci', 
'edu', 
'four'...]
```

list_1 :

```
[('focus', [-1, -2]), 
('four', [-3.3, -1.04]),
...)]

for key in docs_A_rec:
    for word, number_1,number_2  in list_1:
       if word in buffer:
           docs_A_rec[key]['idf'][word] = list_1[word][number_1]
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Thank you.

Comment: Vasilis, you must be more precise in what you post.
We don't know what is templist, what is docs_A_rec.

Comment: docs_A_rec is a dict. At this time think it like a variable x. I just need to pass the 1st value of the inside list.

Comment: Ok I got the error guys. I forgot to put the brackets -.-' ! Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a bug in your second loop, fix it as the following:

```
for key in docs_A_rec:
    for word, (number_1,number_2)  in list_1:
       if word in buffer:
           docs_A_rec[key]['idf'][word] = templist[word][number_1]
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 2):

should be like this:

```
[('focus', [-1, -2]), 
('four', [-3.3, -1.04]),
...)]

for key in docs_A_rec:
    for word, (number_1,number_2)  in list_1:
       if word in buffer:
           docs_A_rec[key]['idf'][word] = list_1[word][number_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> buffer = ['from', 'landi', 'stsci', 'edu', 'four']
>>> list_1 = [('focus', [-1, -2]), ('four', [-3.3, -1.04])]
>>>
>>> for key1 in buffer:
...   for key2 in list_1:
...     if (key1 != key2[0]):
...       continue;
...     print key1
...     print key2[1][0]
...
four
-3.3
>>>
```

so, the following should be enough,

```
for key1 in buffer:
  for key2 in list_1:
    if (key1 == key2[0]):
      list_1[key1][key2[1][0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because there are only 2 items in each tuple in `list_1`:

```
>>> list_1 = [('focus', [-1, -2]), ('four', [-3.3, -1.04])]
>>> list_1[0]
('focus', [-1, -2])
>>> len(list_1[0])
2
>>>
```

But you are asking for 3 ("word", "number_1", and "number_2"):

```
for word, number_1,number_2  in list_1:
```

To fix this problem, slightly alter your for-loop like so:

```
for key in docs_A_rec:
    # Add parenthesis around "number_1 , number_2"
    for word, (number_1, number_2) in list_1:
       if word in buffer:
           docs_A_rec[key]['idf'][word] = list_1[word][number_1]
```

or use indexing:

```
for key in docs_A_rec:
    # Put the second item of each tuple in 'numbers'
    for word, numbers in list_1:
       if word in buffer:
           # Index 'numbers' at 0 to get the first number (the same as number_1)
           docs_A_rec[key]['idf'][word] = list_1[word][numbers[0]]
```